# Deploying meteor application throws MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, meteor, deployment, redhat

The meteor app I'm currently working on should be deployed on an in-house RedHat server.

I used `meteor build <outputdir> --architecture os.linux.86_64` to create the bundle and uploaded it to the target server, which has mongodb 3.2 and nodejs 0.10.40 installed.

The server runs a local mongodb on `port 27017` with the user `meteor` and the database `myapp`. User and db were created in the following manner.

```
use myapp
db.createUser(
 {
   user: "meteor",
   pwd: "meteor",
   roles: [ "readWrite" ]
 }
)
```

Continuing, I did what the README asked me to do and ran the following commands in my untared app bundle.

```
$ (cd programs/server && npm install)
$ export MONGO_URL='mongodb://meteor:meteor@127.0.0.1:27017/myapp'
```

When I first exported the `MONGO_URL` I typed the port wrong and got a `mongo error: auth error` exception after running `node main.js`. After correcting my mistake the exception changed to `Mongo Error: Authentication failed.`

Yet, it is possible to connect without a problem to the mongo shell by typing `mongo -u meteor -p meteor --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017`.

Did anyone had the same problem and found a solution for it?